# multiple slider and average

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i need to display 10 slider-range-min: the last one (the 10th) is the average of the 9 other sliders.

For that i've repeated the same code 9 time (is it optimum?) by changing id each time

```
 $( "#slider-range-min9" ).slider({
                range: "min",
                value: 10,
                min: 1,
                max: 20,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#amount9" ).text( "$" + ui.value );
                }
            });

$( "#amount9" ).text( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min9" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

And for the average i've repeated the same code also and modified the value:

```
value: (($( "#slider-range-min1" ).slider( "value" )+$( "#slider-range-min3" ).slider( "value" )+$( "#slider-range-min2" ).slider( "value" )+$( "#slider-range-min4" ).slider( "value" )+$( "#slider-range-min5" ).slider( "value" )+$( "#slider-range-min6" ).slider( "value" )+$( "#slider-range-min7" ).slider( "value" )+$( "#slider-range-min8" ).slider( "value" )+$( "#slider-range-min9" ).slider( "value" ))/9),
```

The problem is that the value of this slider (the 10th) does'nt change in live, and i've noticed that my page is a little bit heavy.

Is there any other mean to make the same thing with optimised code?

I'll be very thankful

Comment: "i've repeated the same code 9 time (is it optimum?)" Not at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/YPWY8/

```
$(".slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 10,
    min: 1,
    max: 20,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("avg")){
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

        var sliders = $(".slider:not(.avg)");
        var val = 0, len = sliders.length;
        sliders.each(function(i, ele){
            val += $(ele).slider("option", "value");
        });

        var newVal = Math.round(val/len);

        $(".slider.avg").slider("option", "value", newVal);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider avg"></div>
```

Comment: i've tried to display the amount corresponding to each slider, it works but it is not stable :/
  var val = 0, j=1, len = sliders.length;
        sliders.each(function(i, ele){
   $("#amount"+j).text($(ele).slider("option", "value"));
            val += $(ele).slider("option", "value");
   j++;

        });
Html: 
<span id="amount8" ></span>
<div id="slider-range-min8" class="slider"></div>

Answer (score 2):

How about this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Tatas/2/)**?

```
$(".slider").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 10,
    min: 1,
    max: 20,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        var avg = 0;
        $('.slider').each(function() {
            avg += $(this).slider('value');
        });
        $("#amount9").text("$" + avg / 9);
        $("#slider-range-min10").slider('value',avg/9);
    }
});

$("#slider-range-min10").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 10,
    min: 1,
    max: 20
});
​
```